# Gradle share dependencies in a cascade manner between related projects

Tags: gradle

I have the following Java projects structure:

```
Util
 |
  -- Core
      |
       -- Services
      |
       -- Tools
```

The projects: Tools and Services references to Core and Util projects, the thing is that I ended up writing the same dependency over each project, there must be a better way to inherit the dependencies of the referenced projects and add new ones if needed.

I know about multi projects in Gradle, but this is not like a multi project, since I can basically take the Core library, compile it (which will then contain Core + Util libs) and use it in another project.

I wonder what would be the best way to approach this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Repeating the same dependencies in every project is usually reasonable because in a bigger project you'll never know when they become different, and you don't want to deal with compilation/runtime problems when someone changes common dependencies list.

   I believe that it is more pragmatic to add dependency analyser plugin to your build. It will help you to remove unnecessary dependencies and explicitly add transitive dependencies. And if you add this plugin to your build chain, it will help you to keep your dependencies healthy in the future. Pick this plugin here [gradle-dependency-analyze](https://github.com/wfhartford/gradle-dependency-analyze), or maybe there is a better fork or equivalent somewhere.
2. You are actually out of options in your case because there are only two kinds of dependencies: (1) external (some other jar artefact) or (2) internal (another module in a multimodule build).

   2.1 When you use an external maven-like dependency it will come to you with own dependencies (they are named "transitive dependencies"). It means that if you do `compile 'yourgroup:Core:1.0'` then you will get `Util` as a transitive dependency. But as I mentioned above, it is better to list transitive dependencies explicitly if they are used during compilation or to prevent them from being accidentally removed and crash your application in runtime.

   2.2. If your projects live in the same version control repository and usually change and build together, then the multimodule layout is your best choice. In this case, you will refer to `Core` dependency like `compile project(':Util:Core')` and it will grab `Util` as a transitive dependency as well. And you will be able to do what you asked for and define dependencies for `Services` and `Tools` once - inside `subprojects {}` closure in the `Core/build.gradle`.
3. Having multimodule built doesn't limit you from using `Core` library elsewhere. No matter if it is a multimodule build or not, you can always add `maven-publish` plugin to `Core/build.gradle`, execute `publishToMavenLocal` task and reference to `Core.jar` from another project the same way you do for external dependencies.
4. You can always put your common code (like the one which will add common dependencies) in the external gradle file or custom plugin and `apply` it in `Services` and `Tools`.